# In Scala, why `_` can't be used in groupBy here?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, type-inference

I am trying to calculate the occurrence list of each character in a word, my current codes looks like this:

```
"hello"
  .groupBy((x:Char)=>x)
  .map(a=>(a._1, a._2.length))
```

I think the `.groupBy((x:Char)=>x)` looks clumsy and therefore rewrite like this:

```
"hello"
  .groupBy(_)
  .map(a=>(a._1, a._2.length))
```

But then the compiler throw an error

```
Error:(1, 18) missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$1) => "hello".groupBy(x$1).map(((a) => scala.Tuple2(a._1, a._2.length))))
"hello".groupBy(_).map(a=>(a._1, a._2.length))

            ^
```

Does anyone have ideas about this? Or is there better way to write this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`x.groupBy(_)`, like any method `x.foo(_)`, means "turn this method into a function", i.e. `y => x.groupBy(y)`.

Because `_` is used for many things, it *also* can mean "plug in the value here".  However, the "plug in identity" doesn't work because of the meaning above.

You can do `x => x` or `identity` to get what you intend by `_`.