# Automatic type recognition in Scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming, type-inference

I am learning Scala right now. I see that specifying type while assigning to new val is not necessary. But then consider the following code:

```
object MyObject {
  def firstResponse(r: Array[String]): String = r(0)
  def mostFrequent(r: Array[String]): String = { 
    (r groupBy identity mapValues (_.length) maxBy(_._2))._1
  }
  def mostFrequent(r: Array[String], among: Int): String = { mostFrequent(r take among) }

  // throws compile error
  val heuristics = Array(
   firstResponse(_), mostFrequent(_, 3), mostFrequent(_, 4), mostFrequent(_, 5)
  )
}
```

If I change the last line and specify the type explicitly, then the error is gone

```
val heuristics: Array[Array[String] => String] = Array(
  firstResponse, mostFrequent(_, 3), mostFrequent(_, 4), mostFrequent(_, 5)
)
```

What's wrong here?

**Edit:** As [@mdm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45739709/5248896) correctly pointed out,

```
//This works
val heuristics = Array(firstResponse(_), firstResponse(_))
//This does not work
val heuristics = Array(mostFrequent(_,1), mostFrequent(_,2))
```

Open question is, why Scala can determine the type of `firstResponse(_)` correctly while it has difficulty to do the same for `mostFrequent(_,1)`.

Comment: What is the compiler error message?

Comment: @TeWu This is the error: `<console>:20: error: missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$4) => mostFrequent(x$4, 3))
          firstResponse(_), mostFrequent(_, 3), mostFrequent(_, 4), mostFrequent(_, 5)`  You can paste the erroneous code in REPL and check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler complains with something similar to this:

> Error:(28, 29) missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$3: ) => mostFrequent(x$3, 3))

As you probably already figured out, that happens because the compiler cannot figure out automatically (infer) the type of the input parameter of those functions, when you use `_`. More precisely, it can't infer the type of `mostFrequent(_, 3)`.

So, if you give the compiler a nudge, either by `val heuristics: Array[Array[String] => String] =` or by the following:

```
val heuristics = Array(
    (a : Array[String]) => firstResponse(a),
    (a : Array[String]) => mostFrequent(a, 3),
    (a : Array[String]) => mostFrequent(a, 4),
    (a : Array[String]) => mostFrequent(a, 5)
  )
```

Things will work as expected.

Looking at posts about `_` uses like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8000903/what-are-all-the-uses-of-an-underscore-in-scala) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28790701/in-scala-why-cant-be-used-in-groupby-here?rq=1), you will see that it can mean very many things, depending on the context. In this case I suspect the confusion comes from the fact that you are using `_` to transform a call to a method with more than one parameter to an anonymous function.

Notice that both of the following will work fine:

```
val heuristics = Array(
    firstResponse(_),
    firstResponse(_),
    firstResponse(_)
  )

val heuristics2 = Array(
    firstResponse(_),
    mostFrequent(_: Array[String], 3)
  )
```

As to the specific reason why a method with more than one argument cannot be transformed into an anonymous function, while one with one argument can, I will delegate to someone with more in-depth knowledge of the compiler's inference mechanics.

Comment: Thanks @mdm ! `val heuristics = Array(firstResponse(_), firstResponse(_))` is an interesting observation indeed. I would still like to hear about how `firstResponse(_)` and `mostFrequent(_, 2)` differ, so will wait for that.

Comment: The difference is that `fisrtResponse` has only one parameter, while `mostFrequent` has 2. The compiler can always transform a method with one parameter into a function, but apparently cannot do that "generically" for methods with multiple parameters. As to **why** it can't, I will wait for someone that can clarify how the inference works in details, but for future reference, I think your best option is to use the form `mostFrequent(_:Array[String], 3)`.it's the smallest help you need to give to the compiler.

Comment: @mdm The problem is not 1 vs 2 parameters, it's overloaded vs non-overloaded.

Comment: @alexey I thought about that, and tried to change the names of the method, so that mostFrequent has one parameter and mostFrequent2 has two. At that point, both methods were not overloaded, and the compiler did infer the one with one parameter and not the one with two. So it must have to do with that: some substitution that can be done automatically for one argument cannot be done automatically for two+ arguments.

Comment: @mdm Hm. But `mostFrequent(_)` (without removing overloading) doesn't work either. I checked the specification in case it changed in 2.12, but it's as I remembered: `firstResponse(_)` isn't supposed to work.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes when you use `underscores as placeholders` for parameters,
the compiler might not have enough information to infer missing parameter
types. Therefore, you need to explicitly provide type information. **Placeholder syntax** act as a “blank” in the expression that needs to be “filled in" and you can fill any value to it. Therefore, compiler will have no information about the type of this placeholder.

```
val foo = _ + _
//will fail - error: missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$1: <error>, x$2) => x$1.$plus(x$2))
```

The above expression will fail, because compiler will unable to find type of value that fill the placeholder. Therefore, there need to be some way for compiler to know the type. **The one way is to provide type information of variable/method explicitly.**

```
val foo: (String, String) => String =  _ + _
```

The above expression will successfully compiled. Because, compiler resolve type of the parameter from type of variable `foo` (1st and 2nd placeholder are both as `String`).

**In certain case, compiler can resolve the type from value:**

```
List(1,2,3).foreach(println(_))
```

In above case, `List(1,2,3)` is a List of type `Int`, hence compiler will know type information of placeholder in `println(_)` as `Int` which is resolved from value of `List`.

In addition, **you can also provide type of value explicitly in order to let compiler know about type**.

```
val foo =  (_:String) + (_:String) //will return function (String, String) => String
```

In certain case, if your method have only one parameter, then you don't need to provide explicit type parameter otherwise you need to provide type for placeholder syntax as below:

```
scala>   def firstResponse(r: Array[String]): String = r(0)
firstResponse: (r: Array[String])String

scala> val foo = firstResponse(_)    //no need to provide type information
foo: Array[String] => String = <function1>

scala>   def firstResponse2(r: Array[String], index:Int): String = r(index)
firstResponse2: (r: Array[String], index: Int)String

scala> val foo = firstResponse2(_, 3)     //will fail, need to provide type information.
<console>:12: error: missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$1) => firstResponse2(x$1, 3))
       val foo = firstResponse2(_, 3)
                                ^
scala> val foo = firstResponse2((_:Array[String]), 3)
foo: Array[String] => String = <function1>
```

**Now coming to your case:**

```
val heuristics = Array(
   firstResponse(_), mostFrequent(_, 3), mostFrequent(_, 4), mostFrequent(_, 5)
)
```

Here, compiler will have no idea of what is the type because:

1. val heuristics have no type
2. Type for placeholder syntax is not explicitly provided.

You have solve the issue by providing type `Array[Array[String] => String]` to `heuristics val` as in case 1, and hence compiler compiles it fine.

For case 2, you can modify your code as below:

```
val heuristics = Array(
   firstResponse(_), mostFrequent(_:Array[String], 3), mostFrequent(_:Array[String], 4), mostFrequent(_:Array[String], 5)
)
```

Comment: I see that you are pointing towards compiler having difficulty while infering type of _. But, try the following. Define functions `firstResponse` and `mostFrequent` as defined in the question and try `val v = firstResponse(_)` as well as `val v = mostFrequent(_, 3)` . The open question is, why earlier statement compiles and latter does not.

Answer (score 1):

The weird thing is that `val foo = firstResponse(_)` works, because [the specification](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.12/06-expressions.html#translation) directly forbids it:

> If there is no expected type for the function literal, all formal parameter types `Ti` **must** be specified explicitly, and the expected type of `e` is undefined.

I thought that it could be treated as equivalent to [eta-expansion](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.12/06-expressions.html#method-values) `firstResponse _` which worked without expected type because `firstResponse` isn't overloaded, but it's defined to be the other way around: `firstResponse _` means the same as `x => firstResponse(x)`, which is not supposed to work according to the above quote.

So strictly speaking, it appears to be a bug and you *should* write `firstResponse(_: Array[String])` as well.

Though in this case, to avoid repetition I'd provide the expected type as

```
val heuristics = Array[Array[String] => String](
   firstResponse(_), mostFrequent(_, 3), mostFrequent(_, 4), mostFrequent(_, 5)
)
```